# Expected value of a markov history chain

Tags: stochastic-processes

What is $E[X_{n+1}|X_0 = i_0, . . . , X_{n−1} = x_{n−1}, X_n = i]??$ Given that $\sum_j^n jp_{i,j}=i$.

Comment: As written, the quantity whose value you're asking about is not clear.  Is it $\ E\left[X_{n+1}|X_0 = i_0, \dots , X_{n−1} = x_{n−1}, X_n = i\right]\ $?

Comment: @lonzaleggiera sorry edited for clarity. But yes that is what I am asking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Well, since it's a Markov chain,
$$\ E\left[X_{n+1}\,|\,X_0 = i_0, \dots , X_{n−1} = x_{n−1}, X_n = i\right]= E\left[X_{n+1}\,\left|\, X_n = i\right.\right]\ .$$
That is, you can ignore all the conditioning equations except the last.  And
$$
E\left[X_{n+1}\,|\, X_n = i\right]=\sum_{j=1}^njP\left[X_{n+1}=j\,|\,X_n=i\right]
$$
Do you know how to express $\ P\left[X_{n+1}=j\,|\,X_n=i\right]\
$ in terms of the transition matrix (whose entries you've implicitly given as $\ p_{i,j}\ $)?

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation. I see the answer is just i now. But to clarify you last statement about expressing isn't it just $p_i,j$ in the transition matrix?

Comment: Yes, by definition, $\ p_{i,j}=P\left[X_{n+1}=j\,|\,X_n=i\right]\
$.